# Обёртка для примитива Boolean как объект

Tags: java

Возможно ли заставить обёртку для примитива Boolean вести себя как объект?

Например, следующий код:

```
public static void testBoolean(int a, Boolean isLeft) throws Exception {
    if (a > 3) {
        isLeft = Boolean.TRUE;
    } else {
        isLeft = Boolean.FALSE;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Boolean isLeft = Boolean.TRUE;
    testBoolean(5, isLeft);
    System.out.println(isLeft);
    testBoolean(1, isLeft);
    System.out.println(isLeft);
}
```

выводит:

> true
>
> true

Есть ли какой-либо способ заставить изменяться `isLeft` в методе `testBoolean` как объект (чтобы второй раз выводилось `false`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нет, такого способа нету. Объекты ведут себя именно так. Вы спутали со случаем изменения ссылки на объект со случаем изменения (мутации) самого объекта.

В метод `testBoolean` передаётся *ссылка* на объект типа `Boolean` *по значению*.

Внутри метода меняется не сам объект, а лишь ссылка `isLeft` на него! Поскольку в функцию передаётся лишь копия ссылки (в этом смысл передачи по значению), изменения её снаружи не видны. Вот если бы вы как-то меняли сам объект, то тогда да, его изменения были бы видны снаружи.

---

Java не поддерживает передачу ссылок *по ссылке*, но можно сделать грубый хак, и передать вместо ссылки одноэлементный массив:

```
public static void testBoolean(int a, Boolean[] isLeft) throws Exception {
    if (a > 3) {
        isLeft[0] = Boolean.TRUE;
    } else {
        isLeft[0] = Boolean.FALSE;
    }
}
```

https://ideone.com/wa0prq

При этом передаётся копия ссылки на массив, в котором доступен «оригинал» ссылки на `Boolean`.

Точно так же в качестве «контейнера» оригинала ссылки можно использовать `AtomicBoolean` (но он при этом производит ненужную синхронизацию), ну или самостоятельно написать универсальный контейнер:

```
class UniversalContainer<T> {
    T value;
    public UniversalContainer() {}
    public UniversalContainer(T initial) { value = initial; }
    public T get() { return value; }
    public void set(T value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

```
public static void testBoolean(int a, UniversalContainer<Boolean> isLeft) {
    if (a > 3) {
        isLeft.set(Boolean.TRUE);
    } else {
        isLeft.set(Boolean.FALSE);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    UniversalContainer<Boolean> isLeft = new UniversalContainer<Boolean>(Boolean.TRUE);
    testBoolean(5, isLeft);
    System.out.println(isLeft.get());
    testBoolean(1, isLeft);
    System.out.println(isLeft.get());
}
```

https://ideone.com/VwSM19

Comment: Напишите еще, пожалуйста, что можно использовать AtomicBoolean и про любые объеты, которые могут хранить состояние ( например, Reference<Boolean>)

Comment: @AndrewBystrov: Ну, AtomicBoolean использовать как-то несемантично (он всё же ещё и синхронизирует), а вот про `Reference<>` не знал раньше. Сейчас почитаю.

Comment: @AndrewBystrov: А где можно почитать про `Reference<>`? Не нашёл в гугле.

Comment: Я имел в виду про этот [класс](http://javadoc.scijava.org/Java8/java/lang/ref/Reference.html). Может быть пример с Reference я привел плохой. Суть в том, что можно использовать какие ниюдь объекты с состоянием

Comment: @AndrewBystrov: Ага, понял. Про объект с состоянием я написал («Вот если бы вы как-то меняли сам объект, то тогда да, его изменения были бы видны снаружи».) Напишу ещё про `AtomicBoolean`.

Comment: ну да, я это и имел в виду)